# How to solve 'sdk manager path not recognized as an internal or external command' error?

Tags: android, sdk

[image]

Why is my SDK is not opening and telling me the SDK is not recognized as an internal or external command and I need help to update my SDK?

But it keeps telling me the SDK manager is opening but ultimately it won't show up.

Comment: Where is located your SDK?

Comment: the complete path :P

Comment: oh :p 
D:\softwares\SDK ECCLPS\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/uwvkmg

here  is a screenshot of the path

Answer (score 5):

**For anyone, getting this message in the command prompt:**

*'sdkmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command*

On Windows, right click My Computer icon:

```
Properties > Advanced system settings > Advanced (tab) > Environment Variables > System Variables
```

Click on Path, New... and paste in the path to your SDK.

Mine was:

```
C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you have to check two things:

1. Your sdk `location path`
2. Your java `environment variable`

No. 1 solution:

`Window -> Preferences -> Android` and under SDK Location browse your folder containing the SDK and click Apply. Make sure that in the selected folder is a file named SDK Manager.

No 2. solution:

Just reset your java path in `environment variables`.

Answer (score 1):

Since new updates, there are some changes that are not mentioned in the documentation. After unzipping the command line tools package, the top-most directory you'll get is cmdline-tools. Rename the unpacked directory from cmdline-tools to tools, and place it under $C:/Android/cmdline-tools

```
why this location?? 
follow along with this medium article for a better understanding --
```

> https://ksrk.medium.com/install-flutter-without-android-studio-on-window-9d3781172912

now it will look like $C:/Android/cmdline-tools/tools

and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You may have deleted the SDK manager or changed its location. try resetting your SDK manager path manually after locating it.

Comment: I reset it but it's not helping .

Comment: try copying the whole SDK folder from someone else, then delete the original one and paste the new one at the same location with the same name as the last one

Answer (score 0):

I think your SDK path is incorrect, configure your SDK path

from the menu go to `File` -> `Project Structure` then change the `Android SDK Location`.

[image]

Comment: can you explain this more specifically please ?

Comment: @MuhtadiAkif , i have added an image just follow the steps to change the SDK path.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/mh43xs

i just did it but it still tells me that it will show up shortly but it's actually not showing up !!

Comment: and btw i am using Android Developing Tools not Android Studio .

Comment: Can I add you on my Skype or Facebook account? so that I can share my screen live to you ..

Comment: Hi i don´t have skype account but i have whatsapp!-